# Block access for user to change his machine address in C# .NET for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, usergroups

What i want is :

There is one windows app ( made in .NET 3.5, VS2008, C# ) for Windows XP SP2 & SP3

generally users can change there IP or modify their IP Address.

Now,when my apps starts i dont want users to change there IP Address untill my app stops.

Hope now question would be clear.

Need your advice soon.

Recommend solution in C# .NET or VB.NET only.

Comment: And by *machine address* you mean IP, MAC, name or something else?

Comment: If by address you mean ip address, it should be enough to remove the user from local administrators group.

Comment: And what is the further context: Only while your app is running, after your app has run, ...? Why you want to do that?

Comment: @"Klaus Byskov Hoffmann" No users are to be kept in Administrator group only as they are required to have Registry Access

Comment: @GvS Sorry i didnt mention but i want this while my app is running..

Comment: @user491518, put the users in another group and give that group permission to only the relevant registry keys.

Comment: I think if you rephrase the question to what you want to achieve, the stackoverflow readers can come up with a more elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: @deltreme plz hv look @ question nw

Comment: this looks like a truly stupid anti user feature. Users who arn't allowed to change their ip are not members of the administrators group. If they are administrators then its not your place to try and stop them.

Comment: @Chris Becke: Maybe he is the administrator of his "enterprise" and is some application going terribly wrong because of this issue. Indeed this is not normal, and the context is also not clear, but that's what forums like this are for.

Comment: That's the **point** of users no longer running as adminstrator: so you are **forbidden** from taking over their machine. You'll need to setup a kiosk machine, removing all access to Windows Explorer or the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can block the access, but you can monitor the IP address, and when it changes you can roll it back to the old IP using WMI.

Comment: Configuring TCP/IP Settings using WMI and C# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx

Comment: I would only do this, if your users are employees of your company. Also be aware if you are using DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much you can do to temporarily prevent users from changing their IP addresses.

1. On most machines the IP address is controlled by the DHCP server. If this server decides you need to change IP address, you have to follow or your connection is closed.
2. Administrators can change the IP address, you could remove a user from the admin group (but that does not prevent point 1).  But that should mean you have a controlled user base (in an enterprise), and you should be allowed to do that. (And how are you going to put them back into the admin group if they are not an admin)?

Maybe the design of your application is wrong, if it depends on always having the same IP address. Or you should mention it in the "requirements".

For example: for un-interrupted "action", P2P clients (like Bittorrent) depend on having the same IP address, but they do not enforcing this.

Answer (score 1):

> generally users can change there IP or modify their IP Address.

No they don't, it is a very privileged operation.  An administrator account is necessary.  On Vista and Win7 the UAC prompt has to be acknowledged.  Preventing an admin from administering the machine is a lost cause and in general a hostile act.  And pointless, the admin has all the required powers to kill your app.

Fix the real problem.  The days that you could count on having your app run with an admin account are long gone.  Anybody that runs Vista or Win7 is quickly going to uninstall your app.